# How to authenticate via AWS Load Balancer without a session cookie?

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, cookies, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using ALB (Application Load Balancer) from AWS which is handling the authentication as well. For authentication I have IdP services which is working fine for me. There are rules already set to redirect a user to the authentication page if the user is not valid via the load balancer.

Now I need to call an API through postman. In that case, first I need to login via browser and need to give valid credentials. After successful login I can find a Session Cookie in browser which is given by the Load Balancer, then I need to copy the Session Cookie and need to set the cookie in Postman for a successful call of the any API's.

But, my intention was to use just a Bearer Token in postman which is straight forward to use in postman. I need to void the process of copy the session cookie from the browser.

Any opinion please?

Comment: The [ALB authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) options don't appear to support bearer tokens. ALso [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUretN39kWTGOpOEFmQ-3kdA/can-alb-forward-authorization-bearer-tokens-in-http-s-request-to-backend-rather-than-x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken).

Comment: So, this is clear if we want to use postman, we need to copy the session cookie from the browser. @jarmod

Comment: Not clear that would work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572327/how-to-pass-cookies-when-calling-authentication-enabled-aws-application-loadbala).